# Remove duplicates excel standard function does not work

Tags: excel

I have a column in an excel sheet with the following data:

- 5506
- 5802
- 5819
- 5812
- 5381
- 5381
- 5831
- 5831
- 5831
- 5831
- 5831
- 5831
- 5831
- 5818
- 5818
- 5818
- 5818

I wish to extract just the unique numbers from this list.

I use the function:

=INDEX(SKURANGE, MATCH(0, COUNTIF('Form Responses 1'!$E$1:E1, SKURANGE), 0))

Pasted into a range of cells to generate a the new list using CSE.

("SKURANGE" is a Named Range for the source data, 'Form Responses 1'!range is the correct range for the test condition.)

Results:

- 5506
- 5802
- 5819
- 5812
- 5381
- 5831
- 5831
- 5818

Note the duplicate "5831".

Any ideas?

Comment: Check all the 5831 to see if there are spaces and/or other un-printable characters

Answer (score 2):

I have your data pasted in column **A**, In **B1** enter:

=MAX(A1:A17)

In **B2** enter the *array formula*:

```
=MAX(IF(A$1:A$17<B1,A$1:A$17))
```

and copy down.  Not only do you get the uniques, they will be sorted:

[image]

*This takes advantage of the numeric nature of the data.*

Comment: Though if there is a number that has some unprintable character, it just ignores it.  So if that number is unique and has that character or is a number stored as text, it will get ignored and skipped.

Comment: I only mention it because that would be the only reason for the OP to get duplicates, with his formula above.  Though I agree your method is much more elegant.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Can you suggest a method of using some kind of *"helper"* column to cleanup potential junk characters in the raw data ??

Comment: That would be my recommendation.  using an empty column enter a formula something like `=--Trim(Clean(A1))` and hope there are not characters that  cannot be removed through those processes.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Actually your suggestion **IS** perfect.  It will either convert to numeric or reveal the miscreant(s) !